# Unity crashes after set Texture received from dll

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am reading camera frames in cpp and providing them via an method to Unity. The image data seems to get correctly wrapped to Unity, but after _frameTexture.Apply() Unity crashes due to dll caused an Access Violation.

Uniy:

```
private void UpdateTexture()
{
    byte[] data = cppPlugin.GetTexture();
    _frameTexture.LoadRawTextureData(data);
    _frameTexture.Apply();
    _spriteRenderer.material.mainTexture = _frameTexture;
}

public byte[] GetTexture()
{
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(640, 480, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

    byte[] d = new byte[921600];
    GCHandle pixelHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(d, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    IntPtr pixelPtr = pixelHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
    getRawImageRGB(pixelPtr, tex.width, tex.height);
    Debug.Log("got Tex: " + d[12] + " - " + d[13] + " - " + d[14] + " - " + d[15] + " - " + d[16] + " - " + d[17] + " - " + d[18]); //values are correct

    pixelHandle.Free();
    return d.ToArray();
}
```

CPP:

```
extern "C" DECLDIR void getRawImageRGB(unsigned char* data, int width, int height) 
{
    cv::Mat currentFrame = irpose->getFrameRGB();
    std::memcpy(data, currentFrame.data, height*width * 3);
    data[12] = 6;
}
```

Comment: How are you implementing this? the frames of the camera are from the webcam or something alike? or is a camera inside the game?

Comment: its from a camera

Comment: you can try to record the camera inside the unity, check this resource: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture-devices.html

Comment: I do some feature based tracking on cpp level, so i need the camera frames there as well...

Comment: You can create a texture with the camera in unity, and then use the method GetPixels() to save each frame, the other solution will be to create the file for each frame to make it accessible... which I don't think is an option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing from unsigned char to char at Cpp level solved the problem. Strange since it used to work with unsigned before.

Comment: we had to do that with live streaming video-like material for a job.  they were the most awesome client but I still have nightmares  :O